# Read ContentTypePropeties from type msoMetaPropertyTypeUser with VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba, metadata

i create a new Excelsheet with Sharepoint. In this sheet there are a lot of meta properties.
Now i want to update a cell with the username of the creator. But Excel had no access on this property.

How can i read a meta property from type "user".

Please help !

Edit: my property is in ContentTypeProperties collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can use the  CustomXMLParts in the book.The line access the custom xml parts from the workbook.

```
        string value = null;
        string fullPath = "D:\\example.xlsx";
        Application app = new Application();
        Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(fullPath, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        CustomXMLParts obj = book.CustomXMLParts;

        foreach (CustomXMLPart xml in obj)
        {
             value = xml.XML;

        }
```